# Capture input field change when value is dynamically added

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, onchange

I have an application that allows the user to add rows dynamically.
The user is able to select a material on a modal form and the data is populated into a text field.

What I am looking to do is once the values have populated after user selection, the `onChange` event of the textarea will trigger and save back to a table in a database.

I am having trouble getting the fields `onChange` event to trigger after the value has been added to the textarea from a popup selection.

Basically the user finds a material form a list in the modal window, clicks onto the material number and populate the values into the row, at the point of population the `onChange` event should trigger and call a function to save the row data back to the database table.

I have the material input `onChange` as this:

```
onChange="postLineData('1',$(this).val(),$(description_1).val());"
```

but it's not triggering.

I need to have the `row_id`, the material value and description for each dynamically created row posted to the `postLineData` function.

Comment: post your html please

Comment: have you considered using (custom) events?

Comment: The onChange event only fires when your blur that element. Perhaps when you set the field value: `$('dat_input').trigger('blur')` I would also advise you filter empty values too, unless you want that.

Comment: I have figured this out, I added a postLinedata function call into the addmaterial() function and works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured this out, I added a postLinedata function call into the addmaterial() function and works fine.